# What is "force output compare" of ATmega328?

Tags: atmega, comparator

This is the link describing Force Output Compare. I don't quite get it. Does it mean I can force the output of the comparator to say "comparator match" even when it is not?

[ATmega328 online datasheet - Force Output Compare](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-0EC909F9-8FB7-46B2-BF4B-05290662B5C3-en-US-12.1.1/index.html?GUID-B34CB2C4-FC54-46D0-88F2-CE5CCCD4BFA9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual says that

> the OCnx pin will be updated as if a real compare match had occurred.

So yes.